# Iterator variable in Java for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

Say I have this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    // do something in here 
}
```

Will the variable i increment 5 times or 6 times? I had this question on an exam and wrote 6 because I thought that since i started at 0, it would need to be incremented 6 times in order to break the loop conditional.

Comment: 6 times but you could have run this yourself

Comment: Why not add a `println( )` inside the for-loop and run it?

Comment: Why not run this code and have it print out `i`...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose But it should give some idea as to what is happening and why the loop breaks after printing out the digit `5`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` will be incremented **6 times** and the loop will run **6 times**. After the last increment `i` will be equal to 6, the loop will see that the condition `i < 6` is not met, and therefore will break out of the loop.

You should see the difference between an increment and an iteration.

`i=0 at the beginning, the loop runs for the 1st time and i increments to 1`

`i=1 now, the loop runs for the 2nd time and i increments to 2`

`i=2 now, the loop runs for the 3rd time and i increments to 3`

`i=3 now the loop runs for the 4th time and i increments to 4`

`i=4 now, the loop runs for the 5th time and i increments to 5`

`i=5 now, the loop runs for the 6th time and i increments to 6`

`i=6 now, the loop does not run because i < 6 is not true and no increment happens`

As you can see above, there were **6 iterations** and **6 increments**. Note that this may not always be the case where the number of iterations is equal to the number of increments/decrements.

If you define the variable `i` outside of the `for loop` and then print its value out after the loop is finished, you will see that `i` will be equal to 6.

Check this out:

```
int i;    

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
// do something in here 
}

System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as i = 0,1,2,3,4,5 the condition is true, so it should be 5 iterations.
(6 cycles)
You can also add `System.out.print(i);` to see the output.